# How to test that a Python function takes less than a certain time to complete

Tags: python, tdd

I'm using Python's unittest.

I'd like to write a test that ensures a certain method completes before a certain time. I can do this by the usual calculation of the difference between *timestamp after* and *timestamp before*, but I started wondering if

1. is this commonly done in [TDD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development), write tests that fail if a method / function is not efficient and then refactor to make it more efficient?
2. does Python's unittest have a slick way to do this?

Comment: I don't think the test failing would actually mean anything.  It can fail for a variety of reasons, such as different timing on another machine, whatever's running in the background, etc.

Comment: You could try using the [timeit](http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html) module to get how long it takes, then write an assert to make sure it completed in less than x seconds.

Comment: People are too quick to recommend `timeit` for everything related to timing.  The purpose of `timeit` is to microbenchmark small snippets of code.  For real-world timing of real-world applications in real-world situations (where you want to know how long your function will *typically* take to execute under realistic load, not what its fastest possible time is), timestamps are actually the better way to go.

Comment: timing might not be part of TDD officially, but it seems to fit with the way I'm testing and refactoring to watch the time get better.  I tried timeit just now and I'm sorry, but it is terrible. Put my code in a string and run exec on it?  Timestamps work just fine, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with nose [@timed](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/testing_tools.html#nose.tools.timed) decorator. I use it for testing functions with timing. Example:

```
@timed(2.1)
def test():
    func_with_timeout(timeout=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Some companies have tests for the speed of code, sort of a regression test, these try to catch new code that slows down the system and if they catch a problem, you first try to fix the new code so it still performs well and if you are not able to do that then you (the product owner) can decide whether the new feature is worth it.

Regarding TDD: You don't know the running time, so no, you can't write a test with a guess and later refactor the code so it will pass.. unless you work on something very specific and have a non-functional requirement, like an embedded system that has to respond within 50ms...

Comment: About time limit, this may be a requirement. But maybe what you want to say is that it's quite uncommon to have such a requirement on something that would be in the frame of unittest, i.e. for small parts of code.